# Databound URL - Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, data-binding, hyperlink

I am trying to put a bit of code into my website's page that, when clicked, will redirect the user to another page, bound by a piece of data.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid='<%# Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'">Original Ticket</asp:HyperLink>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong that is making it unable to find the "SR_Service_RecID"?

Thanks!

EDIT: My entire "Item Template" code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <h4 style="font-family: 'Adobe Fan Heiti Std B'; font-size: large; font-weight: 500; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; color: #000000">
        <asp:Label ID="SummaryLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>' /></h4>
        <br />
       <asp:HyperLink ID="OriginalTicket" runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid='<% Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'">Original Ticket</asp:HyperLink> 
        <br />
        <
        Problem:<br />
        <asp:Label ID="ProblemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Problem") %>' 
            Font-Bold="False" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Resolution:
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="ResolutionLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Resolution") %>' Font-Bold="False" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/cancel_btn.png" 
            PostBackUrl="~/HomePage.aspx" ToolTip="pointer" />
        <br />

    </ItemTemplate>
```

Essentially, "Summary" "Problem" and "SR_Service_RecID" are all columns in my database. They are databound to when the user clicks which record they wish to view from the page before (a gridview).

EDIT: Just put suggested single quotes in, and I now get an error saying "The server tag is not well formed."

EDIT: Found the answer to my question, thanks to Karl and Garrison Neely.

I needed to change my code to this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="OriginalTicket" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# "https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid=" & Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'>[OriginalTicket]</asp:HyperLink>
```

Closed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Need more information, what is `SR_Service_RecID`?

Comment: It is a column name from my database. This page is a "View Record" page, so, in my select statement, I pull the SR_Service_RecID (Ticket) number from the database. I want to make the last part of the URL pull that number from the database.

Comment: Is your asp:hyperlink part of a databound element ? a gridview ? repeater ? are you placing it in an item template and trying to bind it ? please provide more code and details

Comment: You need a single quote before your Eval statement. or try removing the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

If SR_Service_RecID is a variable that is accessible in your code-behind, all you'll have to do is take out those quotes, so it'd be `'<%= SR_Service_RecID %>'`.  If this is part of a data-bound Control, like a `GridView`, you'd need to use `Eval`, like this: `'<% Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'`.

If none of those options work, please edit your post with more of your ASPX markup, and add any applicable declarations of `SR_Service_RecID` from the code-behind.

Edit:
Now that I see you're using a GridView, try it this way:
Remove your `TemplateField` with the `Hyperlink`, and replace it with a `HyperLinkField`.

```
    <asp:HyperlinkField text="Your Text"
     navigateurl="https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid={0}" 
DataNavigateUrlFields="SR_Service_RecID" 
headertext="Your Header" />
```

Comment: The SR_Service_RecID is part of my database, and is in a Gridview on the page before. When I do the '<% Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>, it keeps the typical blue, underlined url path until I hit the " before SR. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "The SR_Service_RecID is part of my database, and is in a Gridview on the page before."? Are you implying that this logic is spanned across two `.aspx` pages?

Comment: SR_Service_RecID is a column in my database. The gridview is on the page before, yes. I am using the formview template for this page. Please see more code above.

Comment: My answer doesn't work with the way you've got it laid out.  I think you're just missing a ' before `<% Eval`.  Should work once you've added it.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the hash tag (#) Karl mentioned.  The correct form is `NavigateUrl="https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid='<%# Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'"`

Comment: Okay, I think between @GarrisonNeely and my answer you have what you need, does it work?

Comment: That's what I have. But it still says it is not well formed. And the text '<%# Eval is still highlighted blue and underlined as if it was a hyperlink still.

Comment: And all the rest of the Evals are working?  Are you sure SR_Service_RecID is coming across in your data query?

Comment: The other Evals were working properly. I can't even load the page because it still says "The server tag is not well formed."

Answer (score 0):

In your edited post where you show your `ItemTemplate` code, you are missing the `#` (pound symbol) on your `Eval` call. Here is your code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="OriginalTicket" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl="https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid=<% Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'">Original Ticket</asp:HyperLink>
```

It should be this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="OriginalTicket" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl="https://cw.tabinc.com/v4_6_release/services/system_io/Service/fv_sr100_request.rails?service_recid=<%# Eval("SR_Service_RecID") %>'">Original Ticket</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: It still continues to leave the text" <%# Eval " blue, as if it were still a url. And it says "The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: Edited it in the original question. Second block.